# Using django name 'HttpResponse' is not defined

Tags: django, python-3.x

So brand new to Python, trying to get past this django error:

```
NameError at /hello/
name 'HttpResponse' is not defined
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://localhost:61892/hello/
Django Version:
1.11.7
Exception Type:
NameError
Exception Value:
name 'HttpResponse' is not defined
Exception Location:
c:\users\mblaylock\source\repos\mysite\mysite\mysite\views.py in hello, line 6
Python Executable:
c:\users\mblaylock\source\repos\mysite\mysite\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:
3.6.2
Python Path:
['c:\\users\\mblaylock\\source\\repos\\mysite\\mysite',
 'c:\\users\\mblaylock\\source\\repos\\mysite\\mysite',
 'c:\\users\\mblaylock\\source\\repos\\mysite\\mysite\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36',
 'c:\\users\\mblaylock\\source\\repos\\mysite\\mysite\\env',
 'c:\\users\\mblaylock\\source\\repos\\mysite\\mysite\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:
Mon, 13 Nov 2017 18:09:39 +0000
```

My code is:

```
class views(object):

    """description of class"""

    from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

Using Visual Studio for my IDE on Windows 10, if that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you importing it inside a class?

Comment: from django.http import HttpResponse this import statements should be on top of your py file and indentation in python do matters.

Comment: because that is what the instruction are telling me to do:https://djangobook.com/views-urlconfs/

Answer (score 1):

Best approach in this situation is use single method to handle this request(you don't need any class based views here) which shouldn't be inside any class:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request): 
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

If you want to use class based views you need to remember that
when you are importing something in class body it can be inaccessible in method. You should insert import at the top of python file or directly in method.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to have that `class views` line there. Remove it.

Comment: Yup, that is about what it was. Thanks